# A question regarding tenses?

Tags: tense

A couple of hours back, my friend said to me, **"you had me believing in the divine compensation."**

It still confuses me that why should it not have been like this: **you made me believe in the divine compensation.**

Is the former correct? How?  **Had me believing** seems odd to me. Please, help.

Comment: *You had me believing in (X)*... until I finally realized (Y). Had carries the meaning that this condition ended before the present.

Comment: 1. You are on the wrong site. 2. Question marks are only used after questions. Your title is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's a manner of speaking. It means that you moved the other person into a particular thought pattern, possibly against their will or despite their previous ideas, and in a surprising manner.

An example of using this might be: I watched the movie *Superman* and it had me believing a man could fly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**There is an idiomatic expression here:**

**to have someone believing something**, in the present, often used with a gerund,
Compare that to: to have someone believe something.

He has me believing that he is poor. [present tense]

Yesterday, he had me believing he was rich! [past tense]

**Believing him** is not easy in any case.